# How to code in Python to get the ratio (x:y) format of given two numbers or for the percentage of the given two numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Given the number of students and pencils, say students 154 and pencils are 93 how to code in Python to get a ratio.

Output: x:y

Or say given a percentage of two numbers and find the ratio.

Output: x:y

Comment: A ratio is just division, and percentages just means to multiply by 100, so its basic arithmetic. Read up on some examples of [arithmetic in Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/arithmetic_operators_example.htm).

Comment: @costaparas Thanks but I want a code that gives me x : y output as ratio of two numbers or if given a percentage of two numbers.

Comment: Its unclear what your input/output intention is. Do you mean you have these to numbers and you want a simplified ratio of them? As a fraction?

Comment: @costaparasThanks for your response to my query. I found my answer.

Comment: Ok, well done. For future reference, when asking a question its important to be specific on input/output, your current approach taken, what worked, what didn't. This helps give some context to the question.

Comment: If you found your answer please remember to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math 
x = 50
y = 10
print(str(int(round(x / (math.gcd(50, 10)),0))) + ':'+ str(int(round(y / (math.gcd(50, 10)),0))))
```

Output : 5:1

Comment: While this works it's borderline unreadable. i would suggest splitting it up into multiple lines. Furthermore the round operation is not needed, because we know that x and y are divisable by their gcd, because it's their gcd.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the greatest common divisor between you numbers x and y. The `math` library has the function `gcd()` for this.

```
>>> import math
>>> x = 50
>>> y = 10
>>> div = math.gcd(x, y)
```

You can now print the ratio by dividing your original numbers by div:

```
>>> print(f"{x/div}:{y/div)")
5:1
```

In your particular example you will find that the greatest common divider 154 and 93 is 1.

> Side note: If you don't want to reedit your code over and over again,
> use the `input()` function.

### How to find the greatest common divisor?

**(If you want to flex a little)**

The wikipedia article for greatest common divisor references the [Binary GCD Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) as a method for calculating the GCD of two numbers.

> The algorithm reduces the problem of finding the GCD of two
> nonnegative numbers v and u by repeatedly applying these identities:
>
> gcd(0, v) = v, because everything divides zero, and v is the largest
> number that divides v. Similarly, gcd(u, 0) = u.
>
> gcd(2u, 2v) = 2·gcd(u, v)
>
> gcd(2u, v) = gcd(u, v), if v is odd (2 is not a common
> divisor). Similarly, gcd(u, 2v) = gcd(u, v) if u is odd.
>
> gcd(u, v) = gcd(|u − v|, min(u, v)), if u and v are both odd.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return a

    if a == 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a

    #if a is even
    if a % 2 == 0:

        #if b is odd
        if b % 2 == 1:
            return gcd(a/2, b)
        # Both are even
        else:
            return 2 * gcd(a/2, b/2)

    else:
        # a is odd
        if b % 2 == 0:
            # b is even
            return gcd(a, b/2)

        # if a and b are odd a-b must be even
        if (a > b):
            return gcd((a-b)/2, b)
        else:
            return gcd((b-a)/2, a)
```