# How to calculate the ratio between two numbers in python

Tags: python

I have to calculate the ratio between 0.000857179311146189 and 0.026955533883055983 but am unsure how to do this other than by dividing the two numbers.
Is it possible to calculate this with the result in the form 0.001714 : 0.053912

Comment: Why do you want the ratio to be written in terms of those two specific numbers? Why, for instance, did you choose `0.001714` as the numerator rather than `0.000857` or `42` or `99.1`. Because if you're allowed to choose the numerator and denominator, then `print(str(a) + " : " + str(b))` will trivially find a ratio, but I doubt that's the result you want.

Comment: A ratio is a number, your last example is just a representation of a number. So, what else could it be other than the quotient of your 2 numbers?

Comment: The ratio of 0.000857179311146189 and 0.026955533883055983 is 0.000857179311146189:0.026955533883055983, not sure what you want here

Comment: Why not 902 : 28365? Smaller numerator and denominator (than in 1714 : 53912), and much more accurate.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo is correct, why do you specifically choose `0.001714` as the numerator? Either way you can use `fractions.Fraction` in order to represent the ratio (`Fraction(857179311146189, 26955533883055983)`)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fractions` module:

```
from fractions import Fraction

num1 = Fraction(0.000857179311146189)
num2 = Fraction(0.026955533883055983)

ratio = Fraction(num1, num2).limit_denominator()

print(f"{ratio.numerator / 10**6} : {ratio.denominator / 10**6}")
# 0.027671 : 0.870164
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I got my 902 : 28365, except I used their 53912 as the limit so that my fraction is better in all regards.

Answer (score 0):

I understand OP issue, but the 2 pair-numbers you provided is not the same ratio

Your problem is to find the greatest common divisor, for float

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325587/3789481

```
def float_gcd(a, b, rtol = 1e-05, atol = 1e-08):
    t = min(abs(a), abs(b))
    while abs(b) > rtol * t + atol:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

x = 0.000857179311146189
y = 0.026955533883055983 
div = float_gcd(x, y)

print(f"{x/div}:{y/div}")
#Result: 34462.78514615594:1083743.8102297517
```

I believe `34462.78514615594:1083743.8102297517` is the nearest ratio you would like to get, let's check

[image]

For int, we could use math library
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65640573/3789481

```
import math
div = math.gcd(x, y)
print(f"{x/div}:{y/div}")
```

Comment: Why do you think 34462.78514615594 : 1083743.8102297517 is the nearest ratio? Surely 0.000857179311146189 : 0.026955533883055983 itself is the nearest (to itself)?