# I have two averages numbers and I want to find the ratio for them

Tags: python

I have 2 float numbers that are calculated from a csv file dataset.

```
value1 = 10.82500730353491
value2 = 4.057505093955173
```

Now I need to find the ratio of those two variables from the dataset I have.

Here is my current code that I used to extract the means. Now I need to find the ratio.

```
mean_buildingFire = dataset.loc[dataset['INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC'] == '111 - Building fire', 'UNITS_ONSCENE'].mean()
mean_smoke = dataset.loc[dataset['INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC'] == '651 - Smoke scare, odor of smoke', 'UNITS_ONSCENE'].mean()

print(mean_buildingFire)
print(mean_smoke)
```

My current output:

```
10.82500730353491
4.057505093955173
```

How do I find the ratio as whole numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451994/how-to-calculate-the-ratio-between-two-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 1):

`(mean_buildingFire/mean_smoke).as_integer_ratio()`

Comment: Or, for example, `Fraction(mean_buildingFire/mean_smoke).limit_denominator(1000)`.